# Case insensitive LIKE in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-like

Is there any way of using case insensitive LIKE, e.g. `LIKE device_type LIKE '%iphone 7%'` in BigQuery ?

Comment: Why not use "Upper" on both sides ? upper(device_type) LIKE upper('%iphone 7%') ? Or "Lower" ?

Comment: @KMarron didn't thought that will help but it works, you can post it as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use "Upper" on both sides ? `upper(device_type) LIKE upper('%iphone 7%')`? Or "Lower" ?